# The permissions granted to user ' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I Installed SSRS 2008 R2 on Win Server 2008 R2. Every thing is all right, I can open Report Manager and it's Security link to define new users. I can open Report Server page, but when I want to publish my reports on Report Server I faced with this problem:

```
C:\CalibrationReports>C:

C:\CalibrationReports>cd\CalibrationReports\

C:\CalibrationReports>rs.exe -i publishreports.rss -s  http://ndcalibration:8080/ReportServer_SQL2008
```

> rsAccessDenied400The permissions granted to user 'NDCALIBRATION\admin' are insufficient for performing this operation.http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&EvtID=rsAccessDenied&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services10.50.1600.1127OsIndependent1033ReportingServicesLibraryThe permissions granted to user 'NDCALIBRATION\admin' are insufficient for performing this operation.
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The permissions granted to user 'NDCALIBRATION\admin' are insufficient for performing this operation. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user 'NDCALIBRATION\admin' are insufficient for performing this operation.
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.CreateFolder(String Folder, String Parent, Property[] Properties)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.CreateFolder(String Folder, String Parent, Property[] Properties)
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found.
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.CreateDataSource(String DataSource, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, DataSourceDefinition Definition, Property[] Properties)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.CreateDataSource(String DataSource, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, DataSourceDefinition Definition, Property[] Properties)
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found.
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found.
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found.
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found.
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found.
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found.
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/CalibrationReports' cannot be found.
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
>   The command completed successfully

Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this works for you!

Editing the `rsreportserver.config` file

1. Open the `rsreportserver.config` file located at `D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer`.
2. Hit CTRL+F to look up `RSWindowsNegotiate`.
3. Replace `RSWindowsNegotiate` with `RSWindowsBasic`. Save the file and launch the URL.